# How to use apply when each calculated value depends on previous value

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, sapply

I have 3 columns:

1. **installment**
2. **interest**
3. **exposure**

1st row goes like this

installment interest exposure

```
0          0        1000
```

Installment is 0 for 1st row and a constant figure afterwards. Let it be 100.

Interest of ith row = 0.5% * exposure of (i-1) th row

Exposure of ith row = exposure of (i-1)th row - (installment of ith row - interest of ith row)

```
installment interest   exposure

0           0          1000
100         0.005*1000 1000-(100-5)
```

current interest depends of previous exposure and current exposure depends on current interest.This should go on till exposure is 0. I have done this using a for loop in R. But my data is large and I don't want a for loop. **So I need something like an apply or even faster method if possible**

is there any other way to do this without a loop. I'm looking for a speedy process.

Comment: take a look at `dplyr::lag` also post a reproducible example (with a sample of data provided via `dput`) with your for loop so we can check possible results against your desired. I am pretty sure this can be done handled a vectorised manner.

Comment: I think in this case, looping is the most possible way. Because, the new row's value depends on the previous row. And I guess all functions in R work for a specified length of vector or data frame. Or in other word, you have to write the code that execute per row. So, it will need the looping to go through all the rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like loan amortization, you can try to create a formula before coding it.

< Unfortunately, I am not quite sure how to render LaTeX in SO's Markdown here. Sorry for the presentation. >

Let L be starting loan amount, I be installment payment and r be the interest rate.

At period, n=0, outstanding loan amount is L.

At period, n=1, outstanding loan amount is (1+r)*L - I.

At period, n=2, outstanding loan amount is (1+r)^2 * L - (1+r) * I - I.

At period, n=3, outstanding loan amount is (1+r)^3 * L - (1+r)^2 * I - (1+r) * I - I.

At period, n, outstanding loan amount is (1+r)^n * L - I * sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+r)^k.

After which, it is a matter of coding this:

```
amor <- function(L, r, I, nvec) {
    vapply(nvec, 
        function(n) {
            if (n < 1L) stop("n must be > 0.")
            L * (1+r)^n - I * sum((1+r)^(seq_len(n) -1L))
        },
        numeric(1))
}
amor(1000, r, 100, seq_len(12))
```

output:

```
[1]  905.00000  809.52500  713.57262  617.14049  520.22619  422.82732  324.94146  226.56617  127.69900   28.33749  -71.52082 -171.87843
```

The next problem to tackle is "This should go on till exposure is 0". You can **approximate** the total number of periods using n * I > L * (1+r)^n

```
maxN <- round(uniroot(function(n) I*n - (1+r)^n*L, c(1, 1000))$root)
```

Then use `replace` to set those negative numbers to 0.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. I'll check it out and let you know if its matching with my  results. I use PMT function to calculate Installment amount and if I use that value to amortise, I'll always end up at exposure 0

Comment: Hi, Hope you can reply to this. Your function works perfectly for some data for which I've tried. The exposure is naturally converging to 0 as well.   But I have a small issue. I also want to deal with cases where instalment amount is not constant, ie, constant principal, variable instalment loans. How to deal with it?

Comment: You will prob get a faster response from others if u post a new qn. I am not near  computer now